# Proving Rodrigues' formula from Murphy's formula. Legendre polynomials

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I'm following the book "Special functions of mathematical physics and chemistry" by Ian N. Sneddon where he derives Rodrigues formula for the Legendre polynomials

$$ P_n(\mu) = \frac{1}{2^n n!} \frac{d^n}{d\mu^n}(\mu^2 - 1)^n $$

from Murphy's formula

$$ P_n(\mu) = _2F _1 (-n,n+1;1;\frac{1-\mu}{2}) $$

Murphy's formula can be derived from the generating function of the Legendre polynomials (see Sneddon)

$$ (1-2\mu h + h^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(\mu) h^n $$

My problem is that Sneddon derives the reader to the following exercise to complete the proof:

$$ _2 F _1 (-n, \alpha +n;\gamma;x) = \frac{x^{1-\gamma}(1-x)^{\gamma - \alpha}\Gamma(\gamma)}{\Gamma(\gamma+n)} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^{\gamma +n-1}(1-x)^{\alpha - \gamma+n}) $$

And putting $\gamma \to \frac{\alpha}{2} + \frac{1}{2}$ and $ x \to \frac{1-\mu}{2}$ one can deduce

$$ _2 F _1 (-n, \alpha +n;\frac{\alpha + 1}{2};\frac{1-\mu}{2}) = \frac{(\mu^2 - 1)^{\frac{1 - \alpha}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{\alpha + 1}{2})}{2^n\Gamma(\frac{\alpha + 1}{2}+n)} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}((\mu^2 - 1)^{n + \frac{\alpha -1}{2}}) $$

Substituting here $\alpha = 1$ one derives Rodrigues formula because we already have proven Murphy's formula.

My question is how to prove the first of the latter two equations.

Answer (score 1):

It follows from the [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) and  [Pfaff's transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Transformation_formulas).

To avoid confusion, I'm going to use $(a)_{n}$ for the falling factorial and $(a)^{(n)}$ for the rising factorial.

For $n \in \mathbb{N} $, the series representation for $_2 F_{1} (-n, \alpha+n;\gamma;x) $ is the [finite series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_series) $$ \begin{align} _2 F_{1} (-n, \alpha+n;\gamma;x) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-n)^{(k)} (\alpha+n)^{(k)}}{(\gamma)^{(k)}} \frac{x^{k}}{k!} \\ &=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{k} \binom{n}{k}\frac{(\alpha+n)^{(k)}}{(\gamma)^{(k)}} x^{k}. \end{align} $$

Using [the general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule), we have

$$ \begin{align} &\frac{\partial^{n}}{\partial x^{n}} \left( x^{\gamma +n-1}(1-x)^{\alpha-\gamma+n} \right) \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{\partial^{k}}{\partial x^{k}} \left((1-x)^{\alpha-\gamma+n} \right) \frac{\partial^{n-k}}{\partial x^{n-k}} \left(x^{\gamma+n-1} \right) \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (\alpha-\gamma+n)_{k} \, (1-x)^{\alpha-\gamma+n-k}(-1)^{k} \, (\gamma+n-1)_{n-k} \, x^{\gamma+n-1-(n+k)}  \\ &\overset{(1)}{=} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (-1)^{k}(\gamma-\alpha-n)^{(k)}(1-x)^{\alpha-\gamma+n-k}(-1)^{k} \, (-1)^{n-k} (1-\gamma-n)^{(n-k)}x^{\gamma-1+k} \\ &= (-1)^{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{k} \binom{n}{k}(\gamma-\alpha-n)^{(k)}(1-\gamma-n)^{(n-k)} x^{\gamma-1+k}(1-x)^{\alpha-\gamma+n-k}  \\ &= (-1)^{n}x^{\gamma-1} (1-x)^{\alpha-\gamma+n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{k} \binom{n}{k}(\gamma-\alpha-n)^{(k)}(1-\gamma-n)^{(n-k)} \left(\frac{x}{1-x} \right)^{k} \\ &= (-1)^{n} x^{\gamma-1} (1-x)^{\alpha-\gamma+n} \sum_{k=0}^{n}  \binom{n}{k}(\gamma-\alpha-n)^{(k)}(1-\gamma-n)^{(n-k)} \left(\frac{x}{x-1} \right)^{k} \\ &\overset{(2)}{=} (-1)^{n} x^{\gamma-1} (1-x)^{\alpha-\gamma+n} \sum_{k=0}^{n}  \binom{n}{k}(\gamma-\alpha-n)^{(k)} \frac{(-1)^{n+k} (\gamma)^{(n)}}{(\gamma)^{(k)}} \left(\frac{x}{x-1} \right)^{k} \\ &= (\gamma)^{(n)}x^{\gamma-1} (1-x)^{\alpha-\gamma+n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{k} \binom{n}{k}(\gamma-\alpha-n)^{(k)} \frac{ 1}{(\gamma)^{(k)}} \left(\frac{x}{x-1} \right)^{k} \\ &= (\gamma)^{(n)} x^{\gamma-1} (1-x)^{\alpha-\gamma+n} \, _2F_{1} \left(-n, \gamma- \alpha -n; \gamma; \frac{x}{x-1} \right) \\ &\overset{(3)}{=} (\gamma)^{(n)} x^{\gamma-1} (1-x)^{\alpha-\gamma+n} (1-x)^{-n} \, _2F_{1} \left(-n, \alpha +n; \gamma; x \right) \\ &= \frac{\Gamma(\gamma+n)}{\Gamma(\gamma)}x^{\gamma-1} (1-x)^{\alpha-\gamma}  \, _2F_{1} \left(-n, \alpha +n; \gamma; x \right). \end{align}$$

---

$(1)$ $(x)_{n}=(-1)^{n}(-x)^{(n)}$

$(2)$ $(1-\gamma-n)^{(n-k)} = \frac{\Gamma(1-\gamma-k)}{\Gamma(1-\gamma-n)} = \frac{\pi \csc \left(\pi(\gamma+k) \right)}{\Gamma(\gamma+k)} \frac{\Gamma(\gamma+n)}{\pi \csc \left(\pi(\gamma+n) \right)} \frac{\Gamma(\gamma)}{\Gamma(\gamma)} = (-1)^{n+k} \frac{(\gamma)^{(n)}}{(\gamma)^{(k)}}$

$(3)$ [Pfaff's transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Transformation_formulas) in reverse